# Detecting if internet is connected in perl

Tags: perl

I have this perl script to extract the source code of a webpage:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ou = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $url = "http://google.com";
my $source = $ou->get("$url")->decoded_content;
print "$source\n";
```

Now, I want to check the internet status if it is connected or not before extracting the source code .

Comment: Could you name Operating System or Linux Distribution you use? AFAIK "elegant" methods are mostly "unportable".

Comment: Google doesn't like to be crawled automatically, so you might not get usable results unless google.com is just a placeholder for the real domain.

Comment: *"check the internet status"* Do you mean to check whether your own system has an internet connection, or whether the remote server is on line, or something else?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to detect whether a remote server is off line is to attempt to connect to it. Using `LWP` to send a `head` request (instead of `get`) retrieves just the HTTP header information without any content, and you should get a swift response from any server that is on line

The default timeout of `LWP::UserAgent` object is three minutes, so you will need to set it to something much shorter for a rapid test

This program temporarily sets the timeout to 0.5 seconds, sends a head request, and reports that the server is not responding if the result is an error of any sort. The original timeout value is restored before carrying on

Depending on the real server that you want to test, you will need to adjust the timeout carefully to avoid getting false negatives

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use constant URL => 'http://www.google.com/';

use LWP;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

{
    my $to = $ua->timeout(0.5);

    my $res = $ua->head(URL);

    unless ( $res->is_success ) {
        die sprintf "%s is not responding (%s)\n", URL, $res->status_line;
    }

    $ua->timeout($to);
}
```